# join .wav files in android

Tags: android, wav

I was wondering if anyone knew of a library or some code to join .wav files together in android OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Join two WAV files from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java)

Refer the above

Comment: but this is not for android. `javax.sound` is not available in android framework