# How to add silence in front of and to the back of a WAV file

Tags: java, audio

How can I add silence to the beginning and the end of a WAV file with Java?

the length of the silence should be variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this thread: [Join two WAV files from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java)

If you have create a wav that is just a few seconds of silence you could combine your files together to get the required result, silence.wav + myfile.wav + silence.wav

The thread I linked to gives you the barebones code to combine wav file together. - be sure to vote up the answer in the other thread :)

Hope this helps,
Eamonn

Comment: thanks! yes i have found this thread already. the problem is that in my case the length of the silence is dynamic. i.e. i want to define by code how much silence should be added.

Comment: @clamp what about having 1 second of silence in your file, then you can define how many 1 seconds of silence should be added to each end?

Comment: or if 1 second is too long a shorter slience :)

Comment: Upvote for the nice linke and mentioning upvoting other answer :-)

Comment: unfortunately no. the resolution is almost down to 1 millisecond. the final sounds will be used as soundeffects in a game and they should have the playback at very precise times.

Comment: I see combining file would be much too slow then, you could possibly think playing the sound on a new thread and simply putting in a delay before and after the file is played