# concatenate 2 byte arrays and then convert to an audio stream

Tags: java, audio, arrays, javasound

The following is the code that reads audio data from 2 `audio input streams` into a byte array.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.*;

class tester {
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
 try {
  Clip clip_1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
  AudioInputStream ais_1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( new File("D:\\UnderTest\\wavtester_1.wav") );
  clip_1.open( ais_1 );

  Clip clip_2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
  AudioInputStream ais_2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( new File( "D:\\UnderTest\\wavtester_2.wav") );
  clip_2.open( ais_2 );

  byte arr_1[] = new byte[ais_1.available()]; // not the right way ?
  byte arr_2[] = new byte[ais_2.available()];
  ais_1.read( arr_1 );
  ais_2.read( arr_2 );


} catch( Exception exc ) {
  System.out.println( exc );
 }
}
```

}

From the above code i have a byte `array1,array2` for `ais_1,ais_2` . Is there any way to concatenate these 2 byte arrays ( `arr_1,arr_2` ) and then convert them back to an audio stream ? I want to concatenate 2 audio files.

Comment: I'm making this a comment since it isn't a complete answer: I don't think `.available()` will necessarily return the total number of bytes available in the stream. Using `ais_1.frameLength * ais_1.frameSize` should work instead.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the two byte arrays in hand (see my comment), you can concatenate them into a third array like this:

```
byte[] arr_combined = new byte[arr_1.length + arr_2.length];
System.arraycopy(arr_1, 0, arr_combined, 0, arr_1.length);
System.arraycopy(arr_2, 0, arr_combined, arr_1.length, arr_2.length);
```

Still not a complete answer, sorry, as this array is just the sample data - you still need to write out a header followed by the data. I didn't see any way to do this with the AudioSystem api.

**Edit:** try this:

[Join two WAV files from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java)

Comment: If there isn't any way to get audio back from the byte array _(there should be)_,then how can i concatenate two audio files ?