# concatenate multiple audio files in java

Tags: java, audio, merge, concatenation, text-to-speech

i have a java text-to-speech project and I want to concatenate the multiple audio files('ogg' format) so that i play them in one stream, anyone has any idea about it? can java do this? if you can lead me to any resource or tutorial or anything helpful I will be very pleased,
thanks a lot.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/656302/645270)'s an answer which concatenates two WAV-files

Comment: thank you, I hope it will work for 'ogg' files.

Answer (score 0):

For concatenation I would use some external command-line tool via Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder.

Probably, oggcat should work in your case: http://en.flossmanuals.net/ogg-theora/command-line-editing/cat-files/  (it's about video, but ogg container is the same, make sense to try, anyway)

As for playing, there is JOrbis library and probably something else.

Comment: thanks I will look at it :) ,
i have no problem in playing individual files one after another but I want to improve my TTS by merging the diphones so it will become one process (one play).