# How to concatenate multiple audio files in wave format without changing their individual properties in Java

Tags: java, audio, concatenation

I want to concatenate multiple .wav audio files without changing their properties like pitch when they concatenated. I found some of the Stack Overflow links which provide solution for concatenating audio files like:

[Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653861/join-two-wav-files-from-java/656302#656302)

But while concatenating the two, they keep one audio format for the new audio. But I want their individual formats to be retained. For example, if audioClip1 has frequency 44100 and pitch1 and another audio file has frequency 72000 and pitch2 then they should be concatenated with these properties and the final should have this varying characteristics.

Is it possible to do in Java?

Comment: You will have to convert/resample one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to produce another valid `.wav` file?

Yes -> No, it is not possible to have a single file with multiple samplerates.

No -> You can just add the binary data of those 2 files together, prepended with the individual file sizes to split them again. But then again, you could also just make a `.zip`